# how to integrate oauth 1.0 with laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

I am trying to integrate Oauth 1.0 with laravel 8, I am new to oauth integration. I have taken this site for reference. https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-oauth
on adding the providers  I am getting an error as

> Call to undefined method bindShared().

below is my code.

```
'providers' => [
        'Jenssegers\OAuth\OAuthServiceProvider',
    ],
 
    'aliases' => [
        'OAuth' => 'Jenssegers\OAuth\Facades\OAuth',
    ],
```

Anyone, please help me how to integrate oauth 1.0 with laravel. Anyone please tell me the process how to integrate, I am unable to find any other references to complete my task.

Comment: That package was updated 6 years ago. It doesn't seem to support the latest Laravel. Personally I use the [OAuth PECL package](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php). The example there might be a good place to start

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for the response, I have gone through the Oauth PECL package, I found that example is not much descriptive to integrate oauth. I am looking for any link or video where I can find the integration from base

Answer (score 0):

please update your package from composer json to the latest version

```
"jenssegers/oauth":"2.0.2"
```

and update the composer with

```
composer update
```

the issue is that the package not updated from long time and it used bindShared but the laravel framework renamed it with $app->singleton()
try an alternative package because the maintainer don't update it for long time